# Java errors (hsqldb)

Tags: java, linux, debugging, hsqldb

I am trying to start a jar file on Linux:

```
javac db.java #building
java -cp hsqldb.jar:. db
```

The code works fine with the JavaEditor on Wine:

http://pastebin.com/KVDqYydb

Comment: At line 2: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database does not exists: .\Datenbank\meineDB

Comment: As I said it works with the javaeditor. the database exists

Comment: What is `.\Datenbank\meineDB`?? A hard coded string? Maybe a relative path?? show us some code please, help us help you...

Comment: This is the code: http://pastebin.com/pCWFs0XG

Comment: Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, this seems to be the problem:

```
new Datenbankzugriff(".\\Datenbank\\meineDB");
```

Linux uses forward slashes as path separator. Just convert the backslashes to forward slashes, then it should work (also on windows):

[docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess):

> The database file path format can be specified using forward slashes in Windows hosts as well as Linux hosts.